# Gravitational waves formula

Tags: energy, gravitational-waves

Gravitational waves are transmitted in environment in form of waves. Is there any formula for their energy of these waves?

Comment: I heard a rumour they don't contain energy. 
This paper covers 3 mainstream approaches before arguing they are unsatisfactory. http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/11857/1/GRavitational_Wave_Energy.pdf

Comment: Gravitational waves calculations are based around perturbations of flat space metrics, AFAIK, as they are impossible to derivive analytically. (Because GR equations themselves are non linear and coupled) . So it depends on what you mean by formula, I dont think there is a closed solution, rather numerical methods are used.  This might be related, with exact solutions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pp-wave_spacetime